# Date parsing yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss in Android

Tags: java, android, date

My string date --> `2016-10-02T00:00:00.000Z`. I want to get only date from this string. I tried to parse through below coding but it throws me error! I have exactly the same format as mentioned in the string. Any answers?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        try {
            Date myDate = sdf.parse( dateofJoining.replaceAll( "([0-9\\-T]+:[0-9]{2}:[0-9.+]+):([0-9]{2})", "$1$2" ) );
            System.out.println("Date only"+ myDate );
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also tired below code,

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

The error which i get

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-10-02T00:00:00.000Z" (at offset 19)
05-12 00:18:36.613 4330-4330/com.vroom.riderb2b W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse
```

Comment: Ooh, this would come much more naturally if you could use `java.time` on Android. `Instant.parse("2016-10-02T00:00:00.000Z").atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate()`. Well, you can if you get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP); all the date and time classes you need are there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change the simple date format to use: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

in your code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"));  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

If you want to get `date/mm/yy` from it:

use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
// use UTC as timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Log.i("DATE", sdf.format(date));   //previous date object parsed
```

if you want output format: `hour:minute AM/PM`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

**EDIT**

More easier option is to `split` the string in two parts like:

```
String dateString = "2016-10-02T00:00:00.000Z";
String[] separated = dateString.split("T");
separated[0]; // this will contain "2016-10-02"
separated[1]; // this will contain "00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Its again giving date with time stamp: Sun Oct 02 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 2016

Answer (score 3):

try with this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Comment: Its again giving date with time stamp: Sun Oct 02 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 2016  I just need to get date/mm/yy from it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone localTZ = calendar.getTimeZone();    
String format1 = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //will return 2017-01-31
String format2 = "dd"; //will return DAY only like 31
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
sdf.setTimeZone(localTZ );
String result = sdf.format(your_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's worked like this:

```
textView_last_comm.setText(parseDateFormat(passDetailsModel.getLast_comm(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "dd/MM/yy HH:mm"));

  public static String parseDateFormat(String dateToFormat, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) {
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);

Date date = null;
String str = null;

try {
    date = inputFormat.parse(dateToFormat);
    str = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get `date` easily by using `String.substring()` method:

```
String string = "2016-10-02T00:00:00.000Z";
String date = string.substring(0, 10);

Log.d("SUCCESS", "DATE: " + date);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/SUCCESS: DATE: 2016-10-02
```

Comment: The question seemed to ask for a `Date` object rather than a `String`. Also one would prefer to have the input validation that lies in actaully parsing the input rather than blindly taking a substring. Also a little more explanation may be helpful.

Comment: OP is asking about "I want to get only date from this string?". He is not asking about any specific date format. So what's wrong with my answer.